# for loop in a javascript class method not working

Tags: javascript, for-loop

In javascript I am trying to use a for loop in a class's function. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Testing</p>

<p id="thing"></p>


<script>

class test{

  func(){
    for (t=0; t<4; t++){         // If you comment out
    }                            // These lines it works
  }
}

var x = new test();
x.func();
var str1 = "It works!";

document.getElementById("thing").innerHTML = str1;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This gives me this output:

```
Testing
```

but if I comment out the for loop it gives me this output:

```
Testing
It works!
```

I have used for loops before in functions, why can't I / how do I use them in class functions?

Thanks

Comment: Open your browser's developer console, and you'll find out why.

Comment: agree with @squint, a developer should learn to use his tools (console, ide, linting)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not working because the variable `t` is not declared..
You are trying to declare a global variable inner the class scope, which is not possible / valid.

Just declare the variable as a scope variable (`var t = 0`) and it should work

```
func() {
  for (var t = 0; t < 4; t++) {}
}
```